# Variable images, bottom aligned within cards, in rows using pure css

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a container containing "cards": images above with related text below. This kind of thing:

```
<div class = "cards">

  <div class = "card">
    <div class = "image-wrap">
      <img src= "image1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class = "text">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class = "card">
    <div class = "image-wrap">
      <img src= "image2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class = "text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- snip -->

</div>
```

Now, these images have variable height and I would like them to align on their bottom edge within each row. The number of "cards" in each row will vary depending on the responsive breakpoint, so tables won't work here.

This jsfiddle gets part way there: https://jsfiddle.net/uf1d4nx6/4/

..but my goal is to have the bottoms of each of these variable height images align to each other within each row. The height of each card should be the minimum necessary to accomodate the height of the tallest card in that row, with the bottoms of each image in that row lining up. The final product should look like this:
[ideal layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rUJF.png)

I don't want to put the images in their own container, with the text in a separate container because it needs to work with responsive, and there will be variable numbers of "cards" in each row depending on the responsive breakpoint.

Ideally looking for a pure css solution so things don't jump around after the js loads, but I'm not sure if this is currently possible using purely css.

```css
.cards {
   grid-template-columns: calc(1/3*100% - 1/3*10px) calc(1/3*100% - 1/3*10px) calc(1/3*100% - 1/3*10px);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.image-wrap,
.text {
  width: 100%;
}

.image-wrap {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class = "cards">

  <div class = "card">
    <div class = "image-wrap">
      <img src ="https://via.placeholder.com/90x40/fff.jpg"> 
    </div>
     <div class = "text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>    
  </div>
  
  <div class = "card">
    <div class = "image-wrap">
      <img src ="https://via.placeholder.com/90x80/fff.jpg">
     </div>
    <div class = "text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </div>    
  </div>

  <div class = "card">
    <div class = "image-wrap">
      <img src ="https://via.placeholder.com/90x50/fff.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class = "text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>    
  </div>
  
  <div class = "card">
    <div class = "image-wrap">
      <img src ="https://via.placeholder.com/90x50/fff.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class = "text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>    
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that

the height will be the height of image with the maximum height. *In case you really have a wide variety of images), use jquery to set this CSS property.*

> .image-wrap,.text {  height:**80px;** }

the margin left will be 50% (to be defined in pixels) of the size of each image. *In case you really have images with a wide variety of widths), use jquery to set this CSS property inline.*

> .image-wrap img {  position:absolute;  **margin-left:-45px;** 
>   bottom:0;}

```css
.cards {
   grid-template-columns: calc(1/3*100% - 1/3*10px) calc(1/3*100% - 1/3*10px) calc(1/3*100% - 1/3*10px);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.image-wrap,
.text {
  width: 100%;
  height:80px;
}

.image-wrap {
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.image-wrap img {
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:-45px;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class = "cards">

  <div class = "card">
    <div class = "image-wrap">
      <img src ="https://via.placeholder.com/90x40/fff.jpg"> 
    </div>
     <div class = "text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>    
  </div>
  
  <div class = "card">
    <div class = "image-wrap">
      <img src ="https://via.placeholder.com/90x80/fff.jpg">
     </div>
    <div class = "text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </div>    
  </div>

  <div class = "card">
    <div class = "image-wrap">
      <img src ="https://via.placeholder.com/90x50/fff.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class = "text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>    
  </div>
  
  <div class = "card">
    <div class = "image-wrap">
      <img src ="https://via.placeholder.com/90x50/fff.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class = "text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>    
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: I'm hoping to find a solution without any js, just css. I think that might not be possible though..